# Ignore ordinals within an address in python

Tags: python, regex

I wrote this regular expression to match strings like  combinations. Now I want to modify this regular expression and not make it match these strings: ‘st, nd, rd, th’. I want to match all other strings which are in combination like  but the alpha part should not be one of the listed strings.

```
_NUM_ALPHA_PAIR_RE = re.compile(r'[0-9/]+[A-Z,a-z]+', re.I)
```

I want to match: ‘6A’ or ‘6S’ but I do not want to match ‘1ST’ or ‘2nd’

Comment: +1 to Serdalis. If there are a whole lot of false-positives to filter out, filtering them in Python can be a little slow. On the other hand, given pathological input, a regex with negative lookahead can be exponentially slow. And if neither of these matters, it comes down to which is simpler. If you don't even know how to write the regex, it's pretty obvious that filtering is going to be simpler for you…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative lookahead `(?!st|nd|rd|th)`:

```
_NUM_ALPHA_PAIR_RE = re.compile(r'[0-9/]+(?!st|nd|rd|th)[,a-z]+', re.I)
```

---

```
In [125]: import re
In [126]: _NUM_ALPHA_PAIR_RE = re.compile(r'[0-9/]+(?!st|nd|rd|th)[,a-z]+', re.I)

In [127]: _NUM_ALPHA_PAIR_RE.match('6A')
Out[127]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0xb141c98>

In [128]: _NUM_ALPHA_PAIR_RE.match('1ST')
# None
```

Comment: Actually I ended up using this
`_NUM_ALPHA_PAIR_RE = re.compile(r'[0-9/]+(?!st$|nd$|rd$|th$)[,a-z]+', re.I)`